# Mapping csv to display each items in the array in react

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, reactjs, mapping

**I have a products table**

[image: products table]

So I have a column here *product_images* containing arrays of ids(which is used as a source for images).
Using props i am mapping these products like below:

```
render() {
        return (
            <>
                <ul className="row">
                    {this.props.products
                        .map(product => <li className="card col-md-4" key={product.id}>
                            <h2>{product.name}</h2>
                            <p>{product.description}</p>
                            <p>{product.sub_categories}</p>
                            <b>{product.created}</b>
                            {Object.keys(product.product_images)
                                .filter(v => product.product_images[v] != null)
                                .map(product_image =>
                                    <div key={product.product_images}>
                                        <img height='100%' alt='hello' 
                                        src={"IMAGE_PATH" + product.product_images[product_image]} />
                                    </div>
                                )}
                        </li>)}
                </ul>
            </>
        );
    }
```

This gives me each product. What I also want to get is each ids from the array to display multiple images in a product.
I know I am doing something wrong in mapping the objects.
As a beginner in javascript and react, it would be great if you guys can help me out.

I am open to other interesting solutions as well. Thanks

Comment: What is the problem here actually? Does it work properly?

Comment: When using map, you can pass an `index` argument to `map` like `map((product_image, index) => //etc)`

Comment: I am getting this error for now: Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `1575290166391,1575290166394`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks to me that your product_images is CSV of product image ids. if this is the case, try:

```js
{product.product_images.split(',')
  .filter(Boolean) // this is to filter out falsy values if necessary
  .map(product_image =>
      <div key={`${product.id}-${product_image}`}> // concat product id with the image id
          <img height='100%' alt='hello' src={`${IMAGE_PATH}${product_image}`} />
      </div>
  )}
```

Comment: This works. I dont know what you mean by CSV but it is a varchar column holding the ids. Thanks a lot.

Comment: it stands for `comma separated values`. no problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.values((product && product.product_images) || [])
  .filter(productImgArr => productImgArr !== null)
  .map(productImgArr => productImgArr.join(''))
  .map((product_image, index) =>
      <div key={`${product_image}-${index}`}>
          <img height='100%' alt='hello' 
          src={"IMAGE_PATH" + product_image} />
      </div>
  )
```

Comment: So this is mapping to get each integers in the array including the comma not just the two ids.

Comment: What do you mean integers in the array, is that what product_images[index] is? I revised the answer I think that should work

Comment: Yes, product.product_images[index] returns each values in the array like: 1,5,7,5,2,9,0,1,6,6,3,9,1,,,1,5,7,5,2,9,0,1,6,6,3,9,4 for each product. Not 1575290166391 and 1575290166394.